# Python - Sort profile report by tottime

Tags: python, profiling, profiler

Python includes a simple to use [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html):

```
>> import cProfile
>> import re
>> cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")')

      197 function calls (192 primitive calls) in 0.002 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 <string>:1(<module>)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 re.py:212(compile)
    ...
```

How can do the exact same thing, but sorted by `tottime` instead of `standardname`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sort=...` argument of `cProfile.run`:

```
>>> import cProfile
>>> import time
>>> cProfile.run('time.sleep(1); time.monotonic()', sort='tottime')

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.001    1.001    1.001    1.001 {built-in method time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.001    1.001 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.001    1.001 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.monotonic}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also sort by `tottime` when running `cProfile` from the command line like this:

```
python -m cProfile -s tottime my_script.py
```